# Проблема с поисковым меню. Как испраить?

Tags: wordpress

есть данный код:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
                    <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
                </form>
                <?php if (get_search_query(false) !== ''): ?>
                    <p> Результаты поиска по запросу: " <?php the_search_query() ?> ". </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

и есть данный код:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php
 while (have_posts() ) : the_post();
 get_template_part( 'content');
endwhile;
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

есть некоторые записи , которые сделанные в content.php:

```
<div id="post <?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('blocks'); ?>>  
            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <div style="width: 160px; height: 120px;background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>); background-size:cover;" class="top-head"></div>
            <?php endif; ?> 
                    <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div class="desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    <div class="offer"><button>Купить</button></div>
</div>
```

проблема в том что если в поисковом меню ничего вводить и нажать " ENTER " , то появляется ссылка сайт/?s= , и помимо записей , появляются страницы

было так:

[image: картинка]

стало так:

[image: картиночка]

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в вашу форму:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />
```

Запрос станет вида: ?s=asdasd&post_type=post и тогда на странице поиска будут выводится только посты